# Is there an open source C# library for command line/console programs?

Tags: c#, windows

I often write consoles for various things (and I've made my own library - but it's quite limited), I do this mainly because the Windows command line sucks. Is there an open source library I can use for writing such command line applications? By console, I mean a command prompt with auto-complete (tab) and copy/paste.

#### Update:

Please do not recommend that I use something other than cmd.exe (e.g. PowerShell), since PowerShell may not always be available. Also, I'm looking for a library that makes my application behave like a command line interpreter; I'm not looking for a library that helps me parse command arguments.

Comment: Not open-source, but have you considered just deploying whatever you're writing there as PowerShell cmdlets? Tab completion and argument handling for free. And a really nice shell as well.

Comment: To clarify, you want to write a command-line-interpreter type of program that reacts to key presses like TAB or F7, not just lines of input? What version of .NET Framework are you targetting?

Answer (score 3):

[I think I wrote pretty much exactly what you asked for](https://github.com/nerai/CMenu) :)

It's open source on github, is dead simple to use, and has a bunch of examples.

Comment: `NConsoleMenu` is nice and works even in older projects with `.NET Framework 4` :)

Answer (score 1):

I used [Command Line Parser](http://commandline.codeplex.com/) before and it's really good for getting the command line params in a nice, configurable way. Have a look, maybe it'd do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is sort of related, but does not really answer my question. The console needs to be interactive. I will improve my question.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/muget/blob/master/getline.cs) one-file-with-demo library useful.

Answer (score 1):

For tab completion/hinting, i wrote the following lib:

https://github.com/fjunqueira/hinter

It might be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in this article:
http://kamimucode.com/Home.aspx/C-sharp-REPL/1

Maybe you need to implement a REPL:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop

Regards,
Giacomo

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) instead of cmd.